# Pass Values To FillRect

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

I'm using the canvas fillrect function to draw a number of rectangles. I'm hardcoding the coordinates at the moment, but is it possible to pass these to fill rect like a function call to the function? For example if I have 10 sets of coordinates, can I do that using a for loop or something and passing it to fillRect?

```
<body>
 <canvas id="canvas1" width="1224" height="770" position="absolute" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
<script>

var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas1");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
ctx.fillRect(330,0,150,75);
ctx.fillStyle = "#FF4500";
ctx.fillRect(30,80,150,75);

</script>
```

Comment: Sure...why not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah it is easy something like this:

```
<body>
    <canvas id="canvas1" width="1224" height="770" position="absolute" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
   <script>
   var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas1");
   var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
   function Generate(color,x,y,w,h)
   {       
   ctx.fillStyle = color;
   ctx.fillRect(x,y,w,h)
   };

   for(i=0;i<10;i++){
       var height=100*i;
       var width=50*i;
       var x=i+(i*100);
       var y=i+(i*120);
       Generate("red",x,y,width,height);
   }
   </script>
</canvas>
</body>
```

Comment: You don't need to declare the canvas and the context every time you draw a rectangle. This is extremely unefficient

Comment: Sorry didn't pay attention :D fixed it.